# Как реализовать обратную анимация?

Tags: css

Всем привет! Есть анимация при наведении на блок, как сделать так, чтобы после того, как мы уберем курсор с блока - анимация пошла в обратно порядке?

```css
.border-animation {
  --border-width: 0.1em;
  --animation-speed: 0.5s;
  --color: #ffffff;
  color: var(--color);
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 1em;
  transform: scale(1, 0.8);
  border: var(--border-width) solid transparent;
}

.border-animation .border-animation__inner {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Six Caps', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.2em;
  background: #333;
  z-index: 1;
  border: solid var(--border-width) transparent;
}

.border-animation:hover .border-animation__inner {
  animation: background calc(var(--animation-speed) / 5 * 3) forwards ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: calc(var(--animation-speed) / 5 * 2);
}

@-webkit-keyframes background {
  to {
    background: #555;
    text-shadow: 0 0.1em 0.1em #111;
  }
}

@keyframes background {
  to {
    background: #555;
    text-shadow: 0 0.1em 0.1em #111;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="border-animation">
  <div class="border-animation__inner">ardd</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Чем обусловлено использование `animation`, вместо `transition`, для такого простого эффекта?

Comment: Да, я знаю что через transition намного проще это сделать, но я планирую потом усложнить эту анимацию, поэтому мне нужно узнать как сделать анимацию в обратном порядке когда :hover перестает действовать